# Transform scale on click with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to let a button shrink another element with jQuery.
So far I came up with:

```
$( "#img1" ).click(function() {
    $("#img2").css("-moz-transform:scale", "0.7, 0.7"); 
});
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I am currently only worried about serving FireFox. I don't understand why my click function isn't working. I thought I defined everything correctly, I hope you can help out.

Comment: Can you put an `alert("hello");` inside the .click function to make sure that code is even being called? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Your alert works just fine. :)

Comment: Why not just use animate scale from jquery UI? http://api.jqueryui.com/scale-effect/

Comment: Note that jQuery automatically adds vendor prefixes for `.css()` in jQuery 1.8+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$( "#img1" ).click(function() {
  $("#img2").css("-moz-transform", "scale(0.7, 0.7)"); 
});
```